# Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Unknown element: operation

Tags: wsdl, wsdl2apex

```
<wsdl:operation name="postData">
        <soap:operation/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:header message="tns:Message" 

part="Security" use="literal"/>
            <soap:header message="tns:Request" 

part="Request" use="literal"/>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:header message="tns:Response" 

part="Response" use="literal"/>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

This how the Operation part looks . Any alternatives?

Comment: For import , I have placed all  the xsd in place of the import tag. This should be different .

Comment: @SFDCRookie Can you share the WSDL in question?